# Did Euler or did d'Alembert incorporate initial conditions into the solution to the 1D wave equation?

Tags: mathematical-physics

My question is: Who is responsible for incorporating the initial conditions into the one dimensional wave equation solution? References or technical information would be appreciated, especially regarding the development of the integral term.

### Background

If $\phi(t,x)$ is the general solution to the one dimensional wave equation and if the initial conditions $\phi(0,x)$ and $\phi_t(0,x)$ are given, then the formula for the solution incorporating initial conditions is:

Letting $g(x)=\phi(0,x)$ and $h(x)= \phi_t(0,x)$ (with $c=1$),

$$\phi(t,x)= \frac 12[ g(x-t)+ g(x+t) ]+ \frac12 \int_{x-t}^{x+t} h(y)dy .$$

All of this is usually attributed to d'Alembert, however my "References for Euler / d'Alembert" imply that the solution with initial conditions were contributed by Euler.  If so, then the integral term was Euler's work?

### References

References for Euler / d'Alembert:

- Michela Massimi, *Kant and Philosophy of Science Today*, p185
- Amir R. Alexander, *Duel at Dawn: Heroes, Martyrs, and the Rise of Modern Mathematics*, p63
- Manuel D. Salas, *A Shock-Fitting Primer*, p3
- Hankins, *Jean d'Alembert-Science* , p48
- *Leonhard Euler: Life, Work and Legacy*, edited by Robert E. Bradley, Ed Sandifer, p30

References for d'Alemberts formula:

- [D'Alembert's Solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html), MathWorld
- [D'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula), English Wikipedia
- [4.6 PDEs, separation of variables, and the heat equation](http://www.jirka.org/diffyqs/htmlver/diffyqsse32.html), Jiří Lebl website
- R. L. Herman, [d'Alembert Solution of the Wave Equation](http://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/pde1/dAlembert/dAlembert.htm)

Additional sources:

- English translation of what may be Euler's work on this: [*Treatise on the vibration of chords*](https://download.uni-mainz.de/mathematik/Algebraische%20Geometrie/Euler-Kreis%20Mainz/E119Englisch.pdf) (Server of the University of Mainz)
- Original in Latin: Euler, Leonhard, [*De vibratione chordarum exercitatio*](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/119)
  (1749). Euler Archive - All Works. 119.

This question was first asked on:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302304/45664.
It was too old to migrate.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/302304/2451

Comment: Posts should not look like a revision history, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I doubt</del> D’Alembert had the integral term. Weber’s treatise (1901, [p. 213](//archive.org/stream/diepartiellendi01riemgoog#page/n235)) quotes the formula as “originating with” him, but I think only the general form $\Psi(x+ct)+\Phi(x-ct)$ is meant here.

<del>In fact</del> Riemann (1867, [p. 90](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uiug.30112113441676&num=90); [1869](//www.emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?02.0175.04), pp. [111-113](//books.google.com/books?id=jRJTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA111), [188-201](//books.google.com/books?id=jRJTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA188)) — relied on by both Weber (p. 205) and the *Encyklopädie* (1900, [p. 557](//archive.org/stream/p1n1encyklopdied02akaduoft#page/557)) — attributed the integral term to Euler (1750, likely [p. 78](//archive.org/stream/euler-e140#page/n9)).

Euler was using rather different notation, still found in e.g. Forsyth (1929, [p. 488](//archive.org/stream/treatiseondiffer032528mbp#page/n507)). If you want the literal formula, Kline (1972, [p. 513](//archive.org/stream/MathematicalThoughtFromAncientToModernTimes#page/n531)) seems to say it was first written by Lagrange (1762, [p. 27](//archive.org/stream/mlangesdephilo02soci#page/n262)).

**Edit:** It seems I put too much faith in Riemann. Here is from Burkhardt ([1901](//zbmath.org/?q=an:32.0388.02), [p. 12](//archive.org/stream/entwicklungenna01burkgoog#page/n29)):

> In an immediately subsequent second paper <sup>44)</sup>, D’Alembert first details the construction of the curve $y= \Psi(x+t)-\Psi(x-t)$ from the curve $y=\Psi(x)$. Then he turns to the more general assumption that at $t=0$ one arbitrarily prescribes not only the initial ordinate $y=\Sigma(x)$ but also the initial velocity $\partial y\,/ \,\partial t=\sigma(x)$ of each point of the string <sup>45)</sup>. In that case (...)
>   $$
> \Psi(x)-\Psi(-x)=\Sigma(x)
> \tag9
> $$
>   and:
>   $$
> \Psi'(x)-\Psi'(-x)=\sigma(x)
> $$
>   or:
>   $$
> \Psi(x)+\Psi(-x)=\textstyle\int\sigma(x)\,dx.
> \tag{10}
> $$
>
> ---
>
> <sup>44)</sup> [p. 220](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=02-hist/1747&seite:int=249) [1749].
>
> <sup>45)</sup> nº 23, [p. 230](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=02-hist/1747&seite:int=259). ***Riemann’s oft-repeated assertion that this case was first treated by Euler must be based on an oversight of this section***.

Comment: Thanks, particularly for the references.  I am specifically trying to find the original development of the integral term in D'Alemberts Formula--hopefully equations and a drawing showing the geometry and physics.  The antique math and German and French are making it hard.

Comment: Here they seem to state on page 2 (equations 2,3,4) that Euler developed the solution with initial conditions;  https://www.scribd.com/document/32298888/The-Vibrating-String-Controversy-Am-J-Phys-1987-v55-n1-p33-37

Comment: @ Francois Ziegler I have re-opened this question at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15932.  Hope to see your inputs.  Re-opened because of Euler's comments on the velocity IC in the English translation.