# Need a reference for Euler's velocity initial condition for the wave equation

Tags: physics, euler, waves

In DOI: 10.4236/ahs.2020.94019 235 Advances in Historical Studies, p.234
D’Alembert and the Wave Equation: Its Disputes and Controversies, or https://www.scirp.org/pdf/ahs_2020112716312281.pdf p.6 of 11

A. R. E. Oliveira states

> Euler criticized d’Alembert’s work pointing out that the two arbitrary
> functions ϕ and ψ are determined by the initial conditions of the
> problem: ... which represent the initial form of the curve and the
> **distributions of initial velocities**

but he does not give a specific reference.  He does list 5 Euler references--only 1 in English.  My questions are:  *Which is the source which contains this assertion by Euler and is there an English translation?*

Comment: See if this is it (ref. to English translation given in the question): https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7214/did-euler-or-did-dalembert-incorporate-initial-conditions-into-the-solution-to

Comment: On p. 3 of the english translation Euler states "will not be necessary to
consider the velocities of each point of the chord, which simplifies the solution
tremendously." so ???

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you asked the question I linked. The reference to Euler is from Riemann [(1867) fn. 3](https://www.emis.de/classics/Riemann/Trig.pdf). @Ziegler answered your earlier question, that it was D'Alembert [(1747) para. XIII](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015035867830&view=1up&seq=252&skin=2021), not Euler, who incorporated the integral term. Isn't that correct?

Comment: since in the english translation p.3 Euler states "will not be necessary to consider the velocities of each point of the chord, which simplifies the solution tremendously."  I am confused.

Comment: My motivation: The velocity IC is the key to removal of the backward wave in Huygens Principle (see my https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-99049-7 ) so it is very important.